# MVC5 and jQuery template

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-5

I am trying to follow example shown in [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08) session.  I have VS 2013 installed on my machine.  Below is code that deals with jQuery template.  But I am not able to see expected out put.

```
<div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <ul>
        {{each(index,friend) friends}}
        <li>
            ${friend.name}
        </li>
        {{/each}}
    </ul>
</script>
@section scripts{

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            function friend(name) {
                return {
                    name: ko.observable(name)
                };
            }
            var viewModel = {
                firstName: ko.observable('FirstName'),
                lastName: ko.observable('LastName'),
                friends: ko.observableArray([new friend('F1'),new friend('F2'),new friend('F3')])
            };
            viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName()
            },viewModel);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

        });
    </script>
}
```

Update: Please see below for Layout.cshtml file

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    deleted...
    @Styles.Render("~/Content/css")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/modernizr")

</head>
<body>

    Deleted...

    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/koBootStrap")
    @RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
</body>
</html>
```

I was expecting to see list of friends i.e. F1,F2 and F3 but instead its outputing entier script ( see below )

```
{{each(index,friend) friends}}
${friend.name}
{{/each}}
```

Am I missing any jQuery library
I have included below libraries

1. jQuery-1.10.2.js
2. knockout-3.3.0.js

Do I have to include any other library for jQueryTemplate to work?

Update 2:

```
<div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>


@section scripts{


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            function friend(name) {
                return {
                    name: ko.observable(name)
                };
            }
            var viewModel = {
                firstName: ko.observable('Hemant'),
                lastName: ko.observable('Shelar'),
                friends: ko.observableArray([new friend('Atul'), new friend('Atul'), new friend('Atul')])
            };
            viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName()
            }, viewModel);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            alert('ok');

        });
    </script>

    <script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
        <ul>
            {{each(index,friend) friends}}
            <li>
                ${friend.name}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
}
```

Still I can't see  list of friends.  Its outputting entire 'text/html' block as it is.

Update 3: Posting bundle config

```
public class BundleConfig
    {
        // For more information on bundling, visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301862
        public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
        {
            var scriptBundleKoBootStrap = new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/koBootStrap");
            scriptBundleKoBootStrap.Include(new string[] { "~/Scripts/bootstrap.js","~/Scripts/respond.js","~/Scripts/knockout-{version}.js"});
            bundles.Add(scriptBundleKoBootStrap);

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jquery").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery-{version}.js"));

            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryval").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/jquery.validate*"));

            // Use the development version of Modernizr to develop with and learn from. Then, when you're
            // ready for production, use the build tool at http://modernizr.com to pick only the tests you need.
            bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/modernizr").Include(
                        "~/Scripts/modernizr-*"));

            bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                      "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                      "~/Content/site.css"));
        }
    }
```

Comment: is your jQuery being called from the layout page at the bottom.

Comment: Are you seeing the friendsTemplate Script in your output. Any script run in View should really be placed in the "@section scripts{ }" so it loads after Jquery. if it is not in the "@section scripts{ }" it will load before jQuery loads.

Comment: @RichBailo Please refer to Update2 in my question. Still I am having same problem.  You are right, I am seeing the friends Template Script in my output.

Comment: Please post your BundleConfig file

Comment: @RichBailo Please see Update 2.  I have added BundleConfig file.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to template bind in Knockout JS, some more verbose than others.  I would recommend reading through the [template binding documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html). Here is one way of binding to a template.

**Example**

```
<ul data-bind="template: {'friendsTemplate', foreach: friends}"></ul>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your post and your solution worked for me with little modification.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the Knockout.JS at the top of your view page.

```
@{ ViewBag.Title = "Home Page"; }
    <script scr="~/scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js" type="text/javascript">
<div data-bind="template: 'friendsTemplate'"></div>


    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            function friend(name) {
                return {
                    name: ko.observable(name)
                };
            }
            var viewModel = {
                firstName: ko.observable('Hemant'),
                lastName: ko.observable('Shelar'),
                friends: ko.observableArray([new friend('Atul'), new friend('Atul'), new friend('Atul')])
            };
            viewModel.fullName = ko.dependentObservable(function () {
                return this.firstName() + ' ' + this.lastName()
            }, viewModel);

            ko.applyBindings(viewModel);

            alert('ok');

        });
    </script>

    <script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
        <ul>
            {{each(index,friend) friends}}
            <li>
                ${friend.name}
            </li>
            {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </script>
```

Comment: I am still having same problem.

Comment: Is this the location of your Knockout.js file. "/scripts/knockout-1.3.0pre.js" if not please tell me where it is located, try "~/scripts/knockout-1.3.0pre.js".

Comment: What is knockout-1.3.0pre.js?  Do I have to download it from NuGate package?

Comment: You need to add knockout.js to your solution. and then referance it to the location installed. i would just download and follow the instructions here. http://knockoutjs.com/downloads/index.html

Comment: I have added knockout.js to my solution. But you are referring to a file called 'knockout-1.3.0pre.js'  I don't have such file in my scripts folder.

Comment: It was what was in the tutorial. use "~/scripts/knockout-3.3.0.js"

Comment: or what ever your version is, if you used nuget you should have installed knockoutjs package for the 3.3.0 package.

Answer (score 0):

Bellow is a solution that worked for me ( as suggested by Colin Bacon)

```
<ul data-bind="template: {name: 'friendsTemplate',foreach: friends }"></ul>

<script id="friendsTemplate" type="text/html">
    <li data-bind="text: name"></li>
</script>
```

Still I don't know what was wrong with my initial code ( which was demonstrated in [this](https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/MIX/MIX11/FRM08) video)